# How to subtract a percentage from a number in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Here is the code that subtracts two var.

```
function calculate() {

        var myBox1 = document.getElementById('ax').value;   
        var myBox2 = document.getElementById('by').value;
        var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2;
        var myBox3= document.getElementById('myBox3');  
        myBox.value = myResult ;

        }
```

This is to take out percentage.

```
function calculate() {
            var myBox1 = document.getElementById('ax').value;   
            var myBox2 = document.getElementById('by').value;
            var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2;
            var myBox3= document.getElementById('myBox3');  
            var percentage = myResult/myBox3 -2%;
            myBox3.value = myResult ;
}
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question! please reformulate, and elaborate if you expect an answer.

Comment: I don't think those functions do what you think they do. The first one is "subtract" but it multiplies?

Comment: @Sphaso I correct myself. I mean, subtract the percentage from the multiplied result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems in your code, apart from the mixin between subtract and multiplication:

- In your first function you are using `myBox` which is `undefined` you
  should use `myBox3` instead.
- And in your second function, you are dividing a number by an input
  type you should replace `myResult/myBox3-2` with
  `myResult/(myBox3.value-2)`, then to append the `%` sign you need to use
  `+"%"`.
- In the end of your second function the `myBox3` value should take the `percentage` and not the `result` variable.
- Don't use the same name `calculate` for two functions.

This is the updated code:

```
function calculate1() {

  var myBox1 = document.getElementById('ax').value;
  var myBox2 = document.getElementById('by').value;
  var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2;
  var myBox3 = document.getElementById('myBox3');
  myBox3.value = myResult;

}

function calculate2() {
  var myBox1 = document.getElementById('ax').value;
  var myBox2 = document.getElementById('by').value;
  var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2;
  var myBox3 = document.getElementById('myBox3');
  var percentage = myResult / (myBox3.value - 2) +" %";
  myBox3.value = percentage;
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you want to subtract `2%` from the multiplication `result` you should calculate the value of `2%` first, then subtract it from the `result`:

```
function calculate() {
    var myBox1 = document.getElementById('myBox1').value;   
    var myBox2 = document.getElementById('myBox2').value;
    var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2;
    //2% of myResult ===> myResult × 2 ÷ 100
    var substPercentage = myResult*2/100;
    console.log(substPercentage);
    var myBox3 = document.getElementById('myBox3'); 
    var percentage = myResult - substPercentage;
    myBox3.value = percentage;
}
```

This is **[the updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chsdk/bmxdj38u/4/)**.

Comment: I'm looking something like this. Please check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmxdj38u/2/)

Comment: @shajji05 You have to calculate the value of 2% first, then subtract it from the reslut, take a look at my EDIT.

Comment: Thank You very much for your help. It helped me a lot. ty